# Pandas explode row to variable number of rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not sure if "explode" is the right term here. I have a DataFrame with columns `event_id`, `num_steps`, and `avg_time`.

I'd like to end up with a DataFrame where, for each `event_id`, there are `num_steps` rows with each row counting from 0 to `num_steps`.

`event_id, num_steps, avg_time`

`1, 3, 5`

Should become:

`event_id, num_steps, avg_time`

`1, 0, 5`

`1, 1, 5`

`1, 2, 5`

Currently I'm iterating over the dataframe and creating this manually, but I'm wondering if there is any way to do this directly within Pandas to increase processing time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes the index is unique:

```
# toy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'event_id':[1,2],
                  'num_steps':[3,2],
                  'avg_time':[5,4]})

(df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['num_steps'])]
   .assign(num_steps=lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
   .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Output:

```
   event_id  num_steps  avg_time
0         1          0         5
1         1          1         5
2         1          2         5
3         2          0         4
4         2          1         4
```

Answer (score 1):

When we talking about the explode we do `explode` , before that we need convert the max `steps` to `list` of steps .

> Notice make sure your pandas version is later than 0.25.0

```
s=df.groupby(['event_id','avg_time']).num_steps.\
      apply(lambda x : list(range(1,x.iloc[0]+1))).\
        explode().reset_index()
Out[43]: 
   event_id  avg_time num_steps
0         1         5         1
1         1         5         2
2         1         5         3
```